# Break in While Condition , When End of File reached - Shell Scripting

Tags: shell, do-while

I have below piece of script working fine, what it does it takes input from a logfile ($logname) , looks for a start and end pattern (PATTERN_A & PATTERN_B) and prints whatever falls in between the pattern to a output file, it repeats it n number of times for n number of occurrences of the pattern.  The problem I am facing here is it does not break once the end of log file is reached, it keeps on repeating the loop infinitely?  Please suggest something so that it breaks once the log file is read once.

```
while read LINE;    
do    
sed -n "/PATTERN_A/,/PATTERN_B/p" $logname >> $OutputDir/$Final_Output;    
echo " " >> $OutputDir/$Final_Output;    
done < $logname
```

Comment: You are reading the log file line-by-line but have `sed` operating on the entire log file every time. Why? If you just need to do this once for that range just use that `sed` command once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the while loop, sed will handle reading each line. Notice the semicolon instead of the comma:

`sed -n '/PATTERN_A/p; /PATTERN_B/p' $logname`